# Magento 2 knockout js check variable value to specific value

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I want to check knockout variable value equal to 1

below is my code:

[image]

But above code is not working. giving me console error

> Unable to process binding

Comment: Please update the js file where you define `agreementId`.

Comment: file name is module-checkout-agreements\view\frontend\web\template\checkout\checkout-agreements.html i have placed this file in my custom theme